# How to back navigate Ctrl+click files in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> through various function definitions, in Go. Sometimes I drill too deep. I want to move up the stack of visited files. How do I do this in VS Code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `workbench.action.navigateBack` and `workbench.action.navigateForward` to quickly move back and forth between recent cursor positions.

- The default keybinding for `workbench.action.navigateBack` is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd>
- The default keybinding for `workbench.action.navigateForward` is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd>

If your mouse has buttons on the side, you can use them in place of the above keybindings.

Comment: The bindings appear to be a bit different. Go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and paste these values to rekey or at least see the current setting.

Comment: Thank for pointing out the side buttons of the mouse, they were already configurated to navigate back and forward, while the alt + arrow shortcuts were not !

Comment: On my system, the default is `Ctrl Alt -` and `Ctrl Shift -`.

Answer (score 8):

By default:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> moves you back.
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> moves you forward.

To assign your custom key combinations, click on the

`File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts.`

or just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

Type `workbench.action.navigateBack` double click on the found line and assign your shortcut key combination for moving Back and similarly, assign your Forward shortcut by typing `workbench.action.navigateForward` and double clicking on the result.

###### Note:

Pay attention to message while you are trying to assign the new combination. If the key combination already assigned for something else, VsCode will warn you.

Answer (score 3):

On linux, default keybindings are:

workbench.action.navigateBack = <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

workbench.action.navigateForward = <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

[image: Linux default key bindings for navigateBack and navigateForward]